# Command to reboot machine when no users are logged in?

Tags: linux, scripting, users, reboot

Is there a command to reboot a machine whenever the next time that there are no current users logged in occur?

Currently, I have to SSH to machines and use the "w" command to see the users logged in so I know if its okay to reboot or not. If there is a user logged in, I simply can’t reboot because they might have unsaved work left on their Linux box, which is often the case. This can come very time consuming when I have to SSH to the same machine multiple times a week waiting for a time when there are no users logged in.

To make this really simple, I need the following.

A command that will reboot the computer when no users are currently logged in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should help... but it's not a command but short script. I believe there is no command for it. 
It's a script for use with cron, but you can execute it remotely on your machines ofcourse.
I'm using it for rebooting after updates.

```
#!/bin/bash
#  Run this script as a cronjob at some suitable time in the PM, e.g. 10pm.
# Turns off workarea machine if no one is logged on, if someone is logged on
# then checks at 15 minute intervals until a set hour is reached.
# Must be used in conjuntion with the following BIOS settings:
# - Machine powers on in event of AC power being restored after loss
# - Machines turns itself on at a time at least 1 hour after the hour specified
# for $giveupat


# time to give up checking if anyone is logged on at. Specify as an hour on 
#24 clock  e.g. for 7am set to 07. for 7pm set to 19 (though you probably 
#do not want to specify a time in the evening!)
giveupat="07"



# while someone is logged in to the machine...
while [ -n "$(who)" ];do
   if [ "$(date +%H)" != "$giveupat" ];then
   # if time hasn't read the hour at which to give up, sleep 15 minutes
      sleep 900 
   else
     # otherwise stop the script
      exit
   fi
done


# turn off gui login screen
service xdm stop


# reboot
reboot now
```

> Source: linuxquestions.org

Answer (score 2):

Nearly three years late. Found via Google.

For the one-liner fans. For `sudo crontab -e`:

```
26 */3 * * * [ -z "$(/usr/bin/who)" ] && /sbin/reboot
```

Reboot every third hour by 26 minutes if nobody is logged in (`who` returns an empty/zero string).

https://blog.eduonix.com/shell-scripting/understanding-test-conditions-in-linux-shell-scripting/

Find out your absolute path with `which who` or `which reboot`.

Tested on Ubuntu 16.04.6.

---

Now to your question.

```
[ "$(who | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq | wc -l)" -lt 2 ] && reboot
```

Reboot when less than two different users are logged in.

It is far from perfect but may help someone.

Tested on Ubuntu 20.04.1.

Answer (score 1):

If I may be so bold to suggest another approach...

One of the cool things with being `root` is that *you* actually get to decide stuff! So, instead of waiting for users not to be logged in, I would set a fixed time for rebooting the system.

There are ample utilities such as `wall`:

```
DESCRIPTION
       wall  displays  a  message, or the contents of a file, or otherwise its
       standard input, on the terminals of all currently logged in users.
```

To notify logged in users that there will be a reboot, and you could give them enough time to save their work and log out. You can also use the `shutdown` command itself:

```
sudo shutdown -r +10
Shutdown scheduled for Fri 2018-01-05 19:21:46 CET
```

So, I would use something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

echo "Rebooting system shortly. Please save your work and log out" | wall

sleep 60

shutdown -r +10
```

Then run it (for example) the first day of every month at midnight with this crontab entry:

```
0 0 1 * * /usr/local/bin/reboot.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

You can of course name your script what you want, and place it where you like. The above is just an example.

Comment: Most Linux shutdowns have a wall message option built in.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Yeah, I know. Just showing as an example. Plus if you are warned TWICE and still do not heed the warnings, I as a sysadmin feel that you really only have yourself to blame!

Comment: Sadly with the environment i work in, this will not do. No matter how many times i warn the user, if i shutdown their pc with unsaved work, i will be the one to blame.

I appreciate the answer, i did learn from it.